# set ng-model to null on disabled an input

Tags: angularjs

new in angular here.

I have an input field disabled base on the radio button, if the radio button was selected, I first want the input field value to null and then disabled it.

Here is my current example:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.radio" value="selected" /> Sample
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input" ng-disabled="vm.radio='selected'" />
```

When input have the value, it just disabled and keep the input value.

I can do check inside the controller like

```
if(vm.radio=='selected') { vm.input = null }
```

But it only work when I active the function via the button. Is there any good way to handle it at HTML page, on the change event? Not in a controller script.

Comment: put ng-init ="vm.input = null"

Comment: @Avihaym Thank but It didnt remove the input value when I select the radio butotn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/IygRaPlBmLzdnI0jhAQn?p=preview

You can use `ng-change` specifying an expression

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.radio" value="selected" ng-change="vm.radio === 'selected' ? vm.input = '' : '' " /> Sample
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.radio" value="b" /> Sample2
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input" ng-disabled="vm.radio === 'selected'" />
```

Comment: With ng-change="vm.input=null" It did the change. Thank for your explanation.